# How can I improve the efficiency of this algorithm?

Tags: python, encryption, module, overflow, long-integer

I have the following piece of code that does not behave the way that I want.

```
def cipher(plaintext, arr):
    import math
    ciphered = []
    for letter in plaintext:
        ciphered.append(math.pow(ord(letter)-65,arr[1]%arr[0]))
    return ciphered
```

The arguments that are getting to math.pow are 142 and 35. Then it uses that result to find the module with 221. However the result that it is giving me is 206.0 when the result that it should give me is 12. Even when I find this result in wolfram alpha the result is 12. I think that the problem here has to do with an overflow issue. However I do not know how to fix it

Comment: Give us some sample values for `plaintext` and `arr`, and the expected output.

Comment: improving efficiency and not having it give you the right answer are two different things. Generally programmers will tell you to get it working first, THEN optimize the algorithm... at any rate as far as improving its efficiency, one thing to consider is removing the call to import math. importing a library takes a lot of time; if you needed to call that function say 500,000 times that would be extremely inefficient. Instead you would implement the functionality you wanted in the function using simple operations and objects native to python .. should get you started anyway

Comment: The one of the closing parentheses should be before `%arr[0]` and not after. Or you could just replace `%` with `,` to use the fast modular exponentiation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to build is called modular exponentiation, and there's an optimized algorithm for it that will avoid the loss of precision and subsequently incorrect result:

```
def pow_mod(b, e, m):
    """Compute (b^e) mod m."""
    c, e_ = 1, 0
    while e_ < e:
        e_ += 1
        c = (b*c) % m
    return c
```

---

**edit (thanks, @user2357112):**
...or you could just use the built-in `pow`, which does that already. But seeing as you asked for how to improve the efficiency, this is how.

Comment: This already comes with Python; it's what the built-in `pow` (rather than the specifically floating-point `math.pow`) does when you give it 3 arguments.